# How to speed-up download processing on pgAdmin4 query data from UI (one Windows)?

Tags: pgadmin-4

**Correction**
I'm running a simple query on pgAdmin4 to access some data:

```
select date
    ,sum(clicks) as clicks
from db.keyword
group by date
```

The query runs fine and displays my "Data Output" in the box below. The data length is only 737 rows so I want to download it straight from the UI.

I click the "Download as CSV" button (or hit F8) and it takes 15 minutes for the dialog window prompting me to save the data.

It's only 737 rows, so how can I speed this up?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - queries that return results in just seconds or minutes, taking hours to download to CSV. Did you ever manage to figure out why this happens and how to speed up downloads?

Answer (score 0):

You can click the download query result icon on the top right of the query window or press F8.

Comment: F8 and the download button doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click or press, respectively.